# How can I abort a request if the XML file is too large?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, inputstream

In my servlet, I am currently setting the XML file to a variable like this:

```
String xmlFileAsString = CharStreams.toString(new   
         InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Now after this line I can check if the file size is too large etc., but that means the entire file has already been stream and loaded into memory.

Is there a way for me to get the input stream, but while this is streaming the file it should abort if the file size is say above 10MB?

Comment: Sounds like you want to simply want to use `request.getInputStream().read(someBuffer, 0, 1028 * 1028 * 10)` if I'm not mistaking. Afterwards it's a matter of transforming the byte array to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the stream sequentially and count the number of characters read. First don't use `CharStreams` since it already reads the entire file. Create an `InputStreamReader` object:

```
InputStreamReader reader;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

A variable to keep track of the char count:

```
long charCount = 0;
```

And then the code to read the file:

```
char[] cbuf = new char[10240]; // size of the read buffer
int charsRead = reader.read(cbuf); // read first set of chars
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(); // accumulate the data read here

while(charsRead > 0) {
    buffer.append(cbuf, 0, charsRead);
    if (charCount > LIMIT) { // define a LIMIT constant with your size limit
        throw new XMLTooLargeException(); // treat the problem with an exception
    }
}
String xmlFileAsString = buffer.toString(); //if not too large, get the string
```

Comment: I guess a smaller cbuf is better, b/c currently it will read in double the amount before it exists b/c of it exceeding the limit.  Is it slower if you make the cbuf 1024?

Comment: I think 1024 is a good size and won't cause any significant impact. You can also improve performance initializing the StringBuilder with the buffer size using `new StringBuilder(cbuf.length)`.

Comment: Oh, now I see that I typed 10240. I meant 1024. I usually use block sizes like 4096 and 8192. But 1024 is great as well, specially if you have variable data sizes.